# Error executing MySQL query via ebean using RawSql

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean, rawsql

In a Play! 2.x application, I'm trying to send a simple query to a MySQL server using ebean.

My complete class looks as follows:

```
public static List<Venue> search(String query) {
    List<Venue> matches = new ArrayList<Venue>();
    try {
        String q = query.replace(" ", "");

        String sql =    "SELECT  v.id, c.company, c.postcode \n" +
                        "FROM    venue v \n" +
                        "JOIN    contact c ON (c.id = v.id) \n" +
                        "WHERE   REPLACE(c.postcode, ' ', '') LIKE '%" + q + "%' \n" +
                        "    OR  c.company LIKE '%" + q + "%'";

        RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.unparsed(sql)
            .columnMapping("v.id", "id")
            .columnMapping("c.company", "contact.company")
            .columnMapping("c.postcode", "contact.postcode")
            .create();

        Query<Venue> eQ = Ebean.find(Venue.class);

        eQ.setRawSql(rawSql);

        matches = eQ.findList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.eHandler("Venue.search(" + query + ")", e);
    }
    finally {
        return matches;
    }
}
```

However, executing the line...

```
matches = eQ.findList();
```

..results in the following error, which appears to be a MySQL error(?):

```
Query threw SQLException:Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.
Bind values:[]
Query was:
SELECT  v.id, c.company, c.postcode
FROM    venue v
JOIN    contact c ON (c.id = v.id)
WHERE   REPLACE(c.postcode, ' ', '') LIKE '%sw3%'
        OR  c.company LIKE '%sw3%'
```

The query itself is fine, for example I can copy the version from the error message, paste it into MySQL Workbench, and it executes no problem.

Note that I'm using RawSql because I'll need to have more than 2 "OR" clauses, and as far as I know this is the only way to do it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: What are those "\n" in your query ?

Comment: They're just new line characters.  I've tried removing them in case it was something that silly, but same result.

Comment: You have to remove them, because they can be misunderstood by ebean.

Comment: OK, good to know, thanks.  However, although I have now removed them I still get the same error.  One additional note, I've found that if I send a query that results in 0 rows returned, the error does not occur.  So it may not be a MySQL error after all, but rather a problem with mapping SQL results back into the object(?).

Comment: Please add the Venue class source code.

Comment: Many thanks for your input, Nico, got me thinking about it from a different angle.  Solution added as an UPDATE, above...

Comment: Instead of an update, you should create an answer, it will be more readable for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem (or a solution, at least). As "Contact" is a child object of "Venue", you can't map to Contact fields (e.g. "contact.company") without specifying the Contact identifier. So, the following code, with appropriate elements added for contact.id, works:

```
String sql =    "SELECT  v.id, c.id, c.company, c.postcode " +
                "FROM    venue v " +
                "JOIN    contact c ON (c.id = v.id) " +
                "WHERE   REPLACE(c.postcode, ' ', '') LIKE '%" + q + "%' " +
                "    OR  c.company LIKE '%" + q + "%'";

RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.unparsed(sql)
    .columnMapping("v.id", "id")
    .columnMapping("c.id", "contact.id")
    .columnMapping("c.company", "contact.company")
    .columnMapping("c.postcode", "contact.postcode")
    .create();
```

Even better than that, since the routine is just returning a list of "Venue" objects that are matched in the query, it's not even necessary to include the additional fields, so all I really needed was the following (which also works):

```
String sql =    "SELECT  v.id " +
                "FROM    venue v " +
                "JOIN    contact c ON (c.id = v.id) " +
                "WHERE   REPLACE(c.postcode, ' ', '') LIKE '%" + q + "%' " +
                "    OR  c.company LIKE '%" + q + "%'";

RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.unparsed(sql)
    .columnMapping("v.id", "id")
    .create();
```

Comment: I realize this is a looooong time ago for you, but do you remember what you did once you created the `rawSql`? How do you map the result to a Model?