# sqlexception index out of bounds with correct sql-statement

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

i've got an sql statement that works pretty well. but on implementing in my webapp working with play 2.1 i get this error:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.

i found this question here: [Error executing MySQL query via ebean using RawSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977693/error-executing-mysql-query-via-ebean-using-rawsql)
but then i got other exceptions.

i'm trying to get tagged threads that contains a list of tags (same as stack overflow does).
here the sql statement

```
SELECT t.topic 
FROM topic t 
WHERE 3 = (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ta.id ) 
           FROM topic_tag tt 
           INNER JOIN tag ta ON ta.id = tt.tag_id 
           WHERE ta.name IN ('children', 'spain','new') 
           AND tt.topic_id = t.id )
```

in play i do this:

```
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.unparsed(sqlString).create();
result =  find.setRawSql(rawSql).findList();
```

then, i got the out of bounds exception. after that i try to set column mappings:

```
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.unparsed(sqlString)
            .columnMapping("t.topic","topic")
            .columnMapping("t.id","id")
            .columnMapping("ta.name","tagList.name")
            .columnMapping("ta.id","tagList.id")
            .create();
```

now i get a null pointer exception. probably because ebean can't create a query from that.

here some code from my models:

```
@Entity
public class Topic extends Model{

@Id
public Long id;

@Required
public String topic;

@ManyToMany
public List<Tag> tagList;
}


@Entity
public class Tag extends Model {

@Id
public long id;

@Required
public String name;
}
```

after a lot of trying and frustrating i hope that somebody got a hint or a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just wasted few hours with similar problem, I actually managed to solve it by only mapping `id` field for certain kind of model and selecting lesser amount of fields, other values were automatically loaded after that - So basically, error occurred if I tried to select values like:

`.. select e.id, e.name, e.description from exampleTable e ..` and use mappings like:

```
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql)
// map the sql result columns to bean properties
.columnMapping("e.id", "exampleModel.id")
.columnMapping("e.name", "exampleModel.name")
.columnMapping("e.description", "exampleModel.description")
.create();
```

When I changed to select only `e.id` and map:

```
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql)
// map the sql result columns to bean properties
.columnMapping("e.id", "exampleModel.id")
.create();
```

It loaded also `e.name` and `e.description` to model values and errors disappeared. 
(Of course my own query had several joins and were bit more complicated than this, but basics are the same.)

*So to summarize:* when this problem occurs, check that you are not loading anything twice (columnMapping), use System.out.println(""); or similar to check which values are already loaded for your model. Remember to also check annotations such as "@JoinColumn" which might load more data under same model - just based on given `e.id` value. If you dont select and set `e.id` as columnMapping value, then you might need to list all needed fields separately as `.. e.name, e.description ..`

Hopefully these findings helps someone out.